# Add allowed embedding site to all Vimeo videos

Tags: vimeo

I need to add a domain to the list of allowed places to embed videos.  I can do this for all *future* uploads in my settings.  I can do this for existing videos, one by one, using the interface below:

[image]

The issue is that there are hundreds of videos. **Is there any way to add an allowed domain to ***all*** existing videos?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need add the domains in https://vimeo.com/settings/videos/upload_defaults

See screenshot:

[image: Apply to all videos checkbox]

Comment: Perfect... how did I miss that checkbox?!  I'd already added the new site there.